# Downloading, Installing, Importing libraries in Spyder for Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, pyephem

I am trying to run PyEphem on Spyder.

I am extremely new to Python and libraries in general.

Currently it just says that I'm running Spyder in Python 2.7.

1) I would like to run the most up to date version of Python via Spyder and then import or install Pyephem (I'm still unclear on whether I have to install the library first or not), how would I do this? I look online but its very confusing because I don't know what I need to download when I'm presented with a list of links.

2) I would also like to see an explanation of how to properly download a libary like pyephem to be incorporated into use within spyder by typing import spyder.

3) I keep reading that I need pip, but I installed the latest version of Python from the website, ran the IDLE, and type 'pip install pyephem,' as directed, but it says 'install' is invalid syntax. Then when I read that I need to type 'python -m pip install -U pip' to update pip, that is invalid syntax too

I just realized over the past 30 minutes that I'm going to need to familiarize myself with how I download and then install and then import a library for use in Spyder, or some other program that I don't know of that may be better.

Comment: Since you say you're new to Python, please use Anaconda instead of a plain Python installation. It'd save a lot of time and troubles trying to install all packages with `pip` (which is a task for experts, really). Then you need to simply run `conda install ephem`, it can't be easier.

Comment: so once I've done that, I can run the code within spyder?

Comment: Yes, Anaconda comes with Spyder too, so your PyEphem code will run inside Spyder without problems.